# how to capture webservice call response using wsdl2objc ios

Tags: ios, wsdl2objc

I'm developing a app which uses WSDL server. I have generated code from wsdl2objc. I have done with creating soap envelop request header and about to start server call. Can some one of you please suggest me how to capture the response of my server call. Is there any delegate method to capture response like `onload()` method in sudzc WSDL code generated ?

Comment: Are you using wsdl2objc code or sudzc code? 

Sudzc already creates code for you that is executed when response from a method is received. Look at the "handler" methods in the sample code app

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the example coding to handle the response:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  LocalTimeSoapBinding *binding = [[LocalTime LocalTimeSoapBinding] initWithAddress:@"http://www.ripedevelopment.com/webservices/LocalTime.asmx"];
  binding.logXMLInOut = YES;  // to get logging to the console.

  LocalTime_LocalTimeByZipCode *request = [[LocalTime_LocalTimeByZipCode alloc] init];
  request.ZipCode = @"29687";  // insert your zip code here.

  LocalTimeSoapBindingResponse *resp = [binding LocalTimeByZipCodeUsingParameters:request];
  for (id mine in resp.bodyParts)
  {
          if ([mine isKindOfClass:[LocalTime_LocalTimeByZipCodeResponse class]])
          {
                  field.text = [mine LocalTimeByZipCodeResult];
          }
  }
}
```